# back ground colour covering whole screen html & css

Tags: html, css

[image][image]the background color is covering the whole screen I should have red and green

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

section {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<section></section>
```

I expected to have a large green box at the top and a smaller red one at the bottom but I only have a full green screen.

If # the div in styles the red box appears but I don't understand why

Comment: I'm not shure what you are asking, are you trying to have a background color that covers the whole page, what don't you understand about the red box, the red box don't come from the `div` tag, it comes from the `section` tag?

Comment: It works in the snippet.

Comment: thanks for the reply, what it was meant to give me was a green box at the top and a red one at the bottom, what I get is a full screen of green with no red, if I remove the div the red box appears. on its own

Comment: Idk what browser your are using but it works fine on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbtxs59p/), try another browser or add display block on div

Answer (score 0):

Looking very closely and zooming in at your screen image explains what you are actually doing.

Putting a '#" in front of the 'div' changes the CSS selection from looking for <div> elements to looking for elements with < ... id="div" ... >.   '#' is the CSS ID selector.

Without the '#' the CSS matches the two <div> elements and makes them green.

Adding in the '#'  to 'div' matches no elements because there are no elements with ' .. id="div" .. ' so there is nothing matching to make green.   Only the red remains.

Comment: thanks for the answers, there seems to be an issue in the console not displaying correctly, I switched to a new one as recommended by 18jad and it works,

Comment: That's good.  But please note that your posted image above does (seem to) have a '#' in front of the 'div' which will have the effect I described above.

Comment: I put that in, I'm just new I thought it might be like python and commented it out to see if that was the issue  and only allow the red to work

Comment: No problem.  We all are new and/or learning.  You can put comments in CSS with /*comment*/.  You can put comments in HTML with <!--comment-->